# How to show default seekbar or controlls in flutter_vlc_player

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add default seekbar / Controller for this plugin, I tried these attributes is also not working.

**showControls: true,

defaultControlsEnabled: true,**

```
 _vlcPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.file(new File(widget.videoPath),
              hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
              autoPlay: true,
              options: VlcPlayerOptions()
            );

    vlcPlayer = VlcPlayer(
      controller: _vlcPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
```

Comment: @Maxim No I don't find solution.